# How do I configure context broker accept post requests from my remote sensor?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have set my weather station with different sensors attached. My practice until now was to send the sensor data to a web address. But now that I have set up a CentOS 6.6 on a server with its IP address so now I want to send the sensor data directly to that machine that has orion context broker installed.

So my question is, **how do I configure orion context broker to accept these post requests (from the weather station sensors) that are being sent to the CentOS machine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problem sending post requests to a CentOS machine that is running Orion Context Broker. In fact, that is the supported OS for running Orion.

Just make sure you have the port open that Orion will be listening at (by default it's 1026), and that the payload in the post is acceptable.

For example, to send a value you could do a POST to `<host>:<port>/v1/contextEntities/mySensor/attributes` and a payload such as

```
{
  "attributes" : [
  {
    "name" : "temperature",
    "type" : "float",
    "value" : "26.5"
  },
  {
    "name" : "pressure",
    "type" : "integer",
    "value" : "763"
  }
  ]
}
```

Start out simple by doing a GET :1026/version to see if it works and work up to more advanced queries (see the [documentation](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide) for more good stuff :)

Comment: thanks, I will accept this answer as soon as I test it out... I'm still new at linux and curl commands

Comment: in case you find it useful, with curl you woud do ```curl <host>:<port>/version```

Comment: can you define what an acceptable payload is? My current modem is configured to send strings such as "9, 4, 15, 1, 200, 10".
Will context broker be able to interpret those strings?

Comment: I added an example to the answer, taken from the wiki.

Comment: I am just now starting to realize how it works. So what if my smart weather station sends 15 different readings? for example date, reading from wind speed, temp, ground moisture etc. Would that device have to be configured like in the example and send these 15 attributes? Or is there a way, for the sake of data conservation, to send just one: `"attributes" : [
  {
    "name" : "MyWeatherStation",
    "type" : "AllData",
    "value" : "26.5, 14.8, 200, 500, 10, 34.6..."
  },`
and then somehow parse all the conjoined values?

Comment: You have several options: you can have many entities with one attribute, you can have one entity with many attributes (my example), or one entity-one attribute (your example). In the last case you are losing the notification functionality on a per value basis, but other than that is perfectly valid.

Comment: I would personally go with one entity (the weather station) and one attribute for each measurement. You are not really gaining much in terms of storage doing it the other way and you are losing other things (notifications).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74836/discussion-between-vrankela-and-leandroguillen).

Comment: Hi Leandro, I just tried communicating between two centOS machines. I am sending post to the other machine (where I have orion installed and the python script running), and I can see the message getting across (although it is messy because of too much spaces) but in return I get "No JSON object could be decoded". Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi. You should probably create another question for that.

Comment: I did, and I am marking this answered since I will probably add another question when I get to the actual weather statitions...